# pytest: xfail on given exception, pass otherwise

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test that uses `requests` and needs an active connection.

I would like it to `xfail` if the connection is down but pass normally otherwise.

Here is what I tried:

```
from requests import ConnectionError

@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=ConnectionError)
class TestStuff():
    def test_stuff():
        do stuff
```

This will indeed `xfail` if connection is down but it `xpass`es in the general case.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

I can use a try/except:

```
from requests import ConnectionError

class TestStuff():

    def test_stuff():
        try:
            do stuff
        except ConnectionError:
            pass
```

but I get no xfail. The test always passes, but I'm not notified that it couldn't be performed properly.

I guess xfail is meant for systematic errors that may be fixed someday (broken lib,...), not for transient errors like connection errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytest supports imperative xfail from within a test or setup function.

Use the try/except code you have, and include `pytest.xfail('some message')` in the `except` body.

See:
http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#imperative-xfail-from-within-a-test-or-setup-function

Answer (score 2):

Calling `xfail` when `ConnectionError` was caught is a solution.

It is even better to check connection in a fixture (the same way - try-except with `pytest.xfail`) and use that fixture in all tests that need a connection.

That way such fixture will cause all dependent tests to xfail without even running them.

Comment: Good point. Although the connection may be up during the fixture test then break during the tests (ok, unlikely...). Or the connection may be up, but the service (which differs depending on which test is ran) unreachable.